# Log for android app in play console vitals

Tags: android, logging, google-play-console

I have an app in google play and for some reason, I get a rare `IllegalArgumentException` for a method with multiple args. It happens in 0.004% according to google statistics (in my app usage), so there is no way I can reproduce it to know how to solve it, and google play vitals doesnt provide any usable info to what arg was a `NULL`.

There are a lot of log.X (x = d, e, w...) and I know the basics, but what I dont understand is, can I use some of them to get info on an argument that was `NULL` when user was using the app? Can I write a `log.e("TAG", arg4.toString())`, put it in try/catch block and build it for production, so when crash happens, it will print the value of `arg4` in google play vitals?

If not, how do I find out which arg was `NULL` in such a rare case?

Answer (score 0):

The Vitals section in the Play Console reports crashes, not logs, so you can either catch the exception and throw another one containing more data in the message, but AFAIK the message of the exceptions is often removed before being displayed in the Play Console in case it reveals private data about the user.

Another option is to integrate with Firebase and store and collect data, but that might be more effort that it's worth putting in.

If I were you I would check in the source code (of your app, the library you're using, or Android source) what line throws the Illegal argument exception and check what argument is checked at this line.

Finally if that's not an option, you could throw an exception yourself in your code before calling that method, checking if each argument is non null. Depending which line throws, you'll know which argument was null.

Comment: Well thats the problem, I can throw exception myself but all arguments are OK, I cant recreate that situation in which something happens to one of the args to be NULL

Comment: Something doesn't add up. You're saying that the IllegalArgumentException is thrown because an argument is null, but you're also saying that if you check all arguments are non null before calling the method, nothing is null. One of the statements is necessarily wrong.

Comment: Like I wrote in question above, this IAE happens in 0.004% according to google stats. When I check, everything is OK, but once every couple of months I get app crash report with IAE in my method.

Comment: So for this 0.004% of the times, your code that checks for nulls should catch something and you would be able to find the exception with the line it throws so you would know which argument is null.